# Crashes Android Studio 3.2 - DexGuard 8.2.16

Tags: android, dexguard

I've just updated Android Studio to version 3.2. My app is obfuscated in release mode with DexGuard 8.2.16 and till today everything was fine.
After updating to Android Studio 3.2 my app crashes at startup without providing any significant information (crashes android.os.Parcel class) into the logcat. Is anybody experiencing nonsense crashes with this configuration? (AS 3.2, DexGuard 8.2.16). In addition, I would like to add that downgrading AS to 3.1.4 everything turns fine again. Does anybody have any clue about the reason of the crashes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share Stacktrace.

Comment: ^^ Can't help if we don't have a log. What may look like nonsense may actually be insightful to the problem at hand.

Comment: not only the `logcat` would be interesting, but also the relevant output from the build.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to post a detailed logcat on tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Dexguard version 8.2.20 everything turned fine